# get coordinate of array of textview at runtime in android

Tags: android

I am adding 10 textview in linear layout.  and I get all coordinates of all textview.  I use below code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    TextView t[] = new TextView[10];;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            t[i] = new TextView(this);
            t[i].setTag(i);
            String s = "Hello :  "+i;
            t[i].setText(s);
            linear.addView(t[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            float x0 = t[i].getX();
            float y0 =  t[i].getY();
            float y1 = t[i].getWidth();
            float x1 = x0 +  t[i].getHeight();


            Log.d(""+i, "x0 : "+x0 +"  y0 : "+y0);
            Log.d(""+i, "x0 : "+x0 +"  y1 : "+y1);
            Log.d(""+i, "x1 : "+x1 +"  y0 : "+y0);
            Log.d(""+i, "x1 : "+x1 +"  y1 : "+y1);
        }
}
```

All textview is display at screen.  But I get 0 at all point.  What is wrong in this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the LinearLayout hasn't gone through it's Measure and Layout passes yet.  It contains those objects but they are "nothing" right now.

Post a runnable to the LinearLayout and do the same thing:

```
linear.post(new Runnable()) {
   // The view is now visible.  Retrieve the objects and check.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to get the coordinates of the text views after the LinearLayout has had a change to perform measurement and layout of the child views.

Observe the [onLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#onLayout%28boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) event and check the coordinates there.

Answer (score 0):

after `setContentView` it takes a while before the view is actually drawn on the screen. You are doing it immedeately and hence, the views are not there yet... Wait for the `LinearLayout` to be drawn like so:

```
/** Replace your 2nd loop, with the code below*/
linear.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            float x0 = t[i].getX();
            float y0 = t[i].getY();
            float y1 = t[i].getWidth();
            float x1 = x0 + t[i].getHeight();

            Log.d("" + i, "x0 : " + x0 + "  y0 : " + y0);
            Log.d("" + i, "x0 : " + x0 + "  y1 : " + y1);
            Log.d("" + i, "x1 : " + x1 + "  y0 : " + y0);
            Log.d("" + i, "x1 : " + x1 + "  y1 : " + y1);
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to "refresh" your layout, it call invalidate. Only call it in the UI thread though. If you call it in another thread (say a timer), then call postInvalidate.

You need to wait for the layout to measure. Write a runnable after lets say 5 seconds after the for loops.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
    public void run() { 
        //do something here
    }
}, 2000); //delay of 2 seconds
```

or use a handler :-

You can use a handler that somehow acts like a timer

```
Handler delay = new Handler();
delay.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 2000);//time in milliseconds
```

And it calls this:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable()
{   public void run()
    {   // Todo

        // This line is necessary for the next call
        delay.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
}
```